# How to dynamically create subpages/subroutes in NextJS?

Tags: next.js

I want to create subpages dynamically like

```
example.com/test/index1
example.com/test/index2
example.com/test/index3
example.com/test/index4
.......
```

or something like this

```
example.com/test/[index1]
example.com/test/[index2]
example.com/test/[index3]
```

The subpages should be created based on the number of indexes. in the base/parent page

I am totally unable to figure out a way to handle something like this
Help would be much appreciated

Comment: This can be accomplished using dynamic routes. Please try it out after browsing the docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

Answer (score 1):

Nextjs has file system based routing. To create a dynamic route for the app you just need to create a js/ts file with a name similar to `[slug].js`(where slug will be the route param for the dynamic route) in the `pages` directory. In that file, you can write all the logic for `data-fetching` and export a React component as default export which will be used to render the page.

For your use case, the directory structure and some pseudo-code for the page might look something like this

```
// directory structure
- pages/
  - test/
    - [slug].js
```

**In `[slug].js`** The example below uses `getServerSideProps` as data-fetching method which will be used to fetch the data required for the page on request for that page from a client.

```js
// data-fetching methods
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
   // you have access to the route param slug in the ctx object
   const slug = ctx.params.slug 

   // fetch the data required for the page by a database query or from a remote API

   // return the fetched data as props
   return {
       props: /* fetched-data */
   }

}

// the page component
const SomeDynamicPage = (props) => {

 // props will contain the data that was returned from the data-fetching method-
 // getServerSideProps 

 return (
   <>
     <h1>Some page</h1>
     <div>
        /* some content based on the received props*/
     </div>
   </>
 )
}

export default SomeDynamicPage;
```

There are additional data-fetching methods (`getStaticProps`, `getStaticPaths`, `getInitialProps`) which may be useful depending on different use cases. Read more about [data-fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) and [dynamic routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) in nextjs docs.